# Using native python libraries only - can I image processing data such as grey-scale values?

Tags: python, tkinter, grayscale

Is there a way to use Tkinter or another native python library to get the grey-scale values from an image?  I usually use Irfan view to open the image and convert it to B&W.  I am not allowed to install any libraries to test this project out - the network tech will not allow it.  So I am hoping there is a way of doing it.  I would like to have a list of the values if possible from this work.

Comment: Please specify the format of the image - JPEG/PNG/GIF/TIFF/TGA/PPM

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of converting image to gray-scale image using tkinter only:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# load the image
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="sample.png")
# return grayscale data from image
data = root.tk.call(img, "data", "-grayscale")
# update image with grayscale data
img.put(data)

# show the grayscale image
tk.Label(root, image=img).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Note that only PGM, PPM, GIF and PNG formats are supported by `tk.PhotoImage()`.

---

Update: code to convert `data` to `(R, G, B)` values:

```py
# function to convert hex color to (R,G,B)
# example: "#101010" -> (16, 16, 16)
def hex2rgb(hexcolor):
    return int(hexcolor[1:3], 16), int(hexcolor[3:5], 16), int(hexcolor[5:7], 16)

pixels = []
for row in data:
    pixels.append([hex2rgb(c) for c in row.split()])
```

Comment: Thank you, that is amazing!  How can I now go about getting the RBG values from the BW image?

Comment: Actually `data` is the RGB values.

Comment: Yes, when I printed the data string, it is the hex color, but not the RGB (I don't think)

Comment: Right, ok I am trying to use some code to strip the #hashtag and use a converter to change all of the values to the usual number values of (R,G,B), but I am getting an error.  I converted the tuple to a string and then tried to strip the # character, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: As the values for RGB are the same for grayscale color, just use `int(hexcolor[1:3], 16)` to get the color value (`hexcolor` is the hex color string, e.g. "#ababab").

Comment: I am trying to make a list of all of the values - so I was trying to use a for loop to iterate through them, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Added code block to convert `data` to 2D list of (R,G,B) values.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you.  I am curious why the first set of RGB values does not start with a tuple bracket.  Here it is : 0, 0, 0)
It is missing the starting bracket.
I am going to try and figure out how to create a set of lists so that if the image is 50x50, it creates 50 lists with each line being a row of pixels.